# Is this shower base worth fixing?

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile

I’m doing a bathroom remodel, and planning on putting new tile in the shower on the walls. The shower pan to me looks off in the back wall of the shower on the right hand side. It isn’t level on the wall as you can see in the picture. But I’m no expert and I’m wondering if anyone with experience would judge this to be good enough.

If it should be redone, would the process to fix it be to scrape off the old tile, level it with some concrete, and then re-tile?

[image]

Comment: Ecnerwal thinks it looks properly sloped for drainage, and it should have a slight slope towards the drain on all sides. TBH, the picture isn't clear enough to see what's going on. Can you make the description more explicit if what you're referring to is not expected drainage slope?

Comment: "Can it be fixed" is a question that could, with much more detail, be answered. "Is it worth fixing" is a question only you can decide based on your abilities and willingness to spend money.

Answer (score 2):

It's **not supposed** to be **level**. If it was level, it would not drain.

It appears to slope towards the drain, which is Actually A Good Thing ®

But feel free to demolish it and build one dead level if you need a learning experience.

Comment: I wasn’t very clear in the description, I know it should slope towards the drain, I was referring to the fact that where the wall meets the the base on the back wall (right side), it is not level *in that spot*. But judging from the comments, minor flaws like this are not a huge deal, and I appreciate that perspective.

Comment: @pythonweb  Cut your new tile  to fit where the base is not level so you don't have a straight grout line right at that point.

Answer (score 2):

From the picture there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the base.
The question you have to answer is;  Did you have any problems with it?

If it drained properly and did not leak, keep it.
If it caused problems in the past, now is the time to replace it.

BTW you can tile over the base and the walls. There are kits to easily raise the drain for the extra height of the new tile and thin set that allow you to tile over tile.

Answer (score 1):

This shower floor is funnel shaped (an inverted cone) this gives a slight slope on the floor to allow drainage,  this is not the only practical shape for a shower floor, but is certainly a valid way to do it.

Some builders make the floor slope to the drain from the same level on each wall, giving an inverted pyramid shape this makes the floor slope unevenly.  It being steeper between the drain and the nearest walls, so this plan works best if the drain is near the middle of the floor, as then the slopes are more equal.

Which you should choose,  well that's decorating advice, and thus off-topic.